# I am trying to make a game like flappy bird in unity but my flap only works when using ForceMode.Impulse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity I am trying to make a game a bit like Flappy Bird. When I tried out my code, the player would only flap up if the force mode was `ForceMode.Impulse` so gravity affected it and it had some weird jumping. I am using a rigidbody to add force to the player. Here is the full code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Flap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public KeyCode flapKey = KeyCode.Space;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    public float flapPower = 5f;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(flapKey))
        {
            BirdFlap();
        }
    }

    private void BirdFlap()
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * flapPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you guys know, I want the flappy bird to flap and gravity not affect how high it flaps, right now if the bird is falling the bird jumps a tiny bit, but if it is going up, it jumps higher than the pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `AddForce` to make the bird flap you should set the velocity directly. `AddForce` will add to the bodys velocity, which means that it will keep the momentum it already had. To achieve the effect you want you should set the velocity so that it gets the same upwards speed no matter its original speed. You could do that like this:

```cs
private void BirdFlap()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, flapPower, rb.velocity.z);
}
```